# Response is not coming sometime in paypal pro api

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I am using paypal pro in sandbox mode.I have set right api username, password, signature for api.

I am using demo credit card no : '4111111111111111',cvv no : '123', ex date : 01/2016.  But sometime the response is returning blank. I am using AngellEYE_PHPClass. The response array is below.

Array
(
    [ERRORS] => Array
        (
        )

```
[REQUESTDATA] => Array
    (
        [USER] => ######################
        [PWD] => #################
        [VERSION] => ###############
        [BUTTONSOURCE] => AngellEYE_PHPClass
        [SIGNATURE] => #######################
        [METHOD] => CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile
        [TOKEN] => 
        [SUBSCRIBERNAME] => Tom Company XX
        [PROFILESTARTDATE] => 2014-11-25 23:29:21
        [PROFILEREFERENCE] => 
        [DESC] => Subscription For business
        [MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS] => 2
        [AUTOBILLAMT] => 
        [TRIALBILLINGPERIOD] => 
        [TRIALBILLINGFREQUENCY] => 
        [TRIALTOTALBILLINGCYCLES] => 
        [TRIALAMT] => 
        [BILLINGPERIOD] => Month
        [BILLINGFREQUENCY] => 1
        [TOTALBILLINGCYCLES] => 0
        [AMT] => 5.00
        [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
        [SHIPPINGAMT] => 
        [TAXAMT] => 
        [INITAMT] => 
        [FAILEDINITAMTACTION] => 
        [CREDITCARDTYPE] => Visa
        [ACCT] => ########################
        [EXPDATE] => 012016
        [CVV2] => 123
        [STARTDATE] => 
        [ISSUENUMBER] => 
        [EMAIL] => #####################
        [PAYERID] => 
        [PAYERSTATUS] => 
        [BUSINESS] => 
        [SALUTATION] => 
        [FIRSTNAME] => Tom Company
        [MIDDLENAME] => 
        [LASTNAME] => Tom Company
        [SUFFIX] => 
        [STREET] => Kolkata
        [STREET2] => 
        [CITY] => Kolkata
        [STATE] => West Bengal
        [COUNTRYCODE] => IN
        [ZIP] => 700001
        [PHONENUM] => 
        [SHIPTONAME] => 
        [SHIPTOSTREET] => 
        [SHIPTOSTREET2] => 
        [SHIPTOCITY] => 
        [SHIPTOSTATE] => 
        [SHIPTOZIP] => 
        [SHIPTOCOUNTRY] => 
        [SHIPTOPHONENUM] => 
    )

[RAWREQUEST] => USER=#############&PWD=############&VERSION=##########&BUTTONSOURCE=AngellEYE_PHPClass&SIGNATURE=#####################################&METHOD=CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile&TOKEN=&SUBSCRIBERNAME=Tom+Company+XX&PROFILESTARTDATE=2014-11-25+23%3A29%3A21&PROFILEREFERENCE=&DESC=Subscription+For+business&MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS=2&AUTOBILLAMT=&TRIALBILLINGPERIOD=&TRIALBILLINGFREQUENCY=&TRIALTOTALBILLINGCYCLES=&TRIALAMT=&BILLINGPERIOD=Month&BILLINGFREQUENCY=1&TOTALBILLINGCYCLES=0&AMT=5.00&CURRENCYCODE=USD&SHIPPINGAMT=&TAXAMT=&INITAMT=&FAILEDINITAMTACTION=&CREDITCARDTYPE=Visa&ACCT=4111111111111111&EXPDATE=012016&CVV2=123&STARTDATE=&ISSUENUMBER=&EMAIL=#################&PAYERID=&PAYERSTATUS=&BUSINESS=&SALUTATION=&FIRSTNAME=Tom+Company&MIDDLENAME=&LASTNAME=Tom+Company&SUFFIX=&STREET=Kolkata&STREET2=&CITY=Kolkata&STATE=West+Bengal&COUNTRYCODE=IN&ZIP=700001&PHONENUM=&SHIPTONAME=&SHIPTOSTREET=&SHIPTOSTREET2=&SHIPTOCITY=&SHIPTOSTATE=&SHIPTOZIP=&SHIPTOCOUNTRY=&SHIPTOPHONENUM=

[RAWRESPONSE] =>
```

)

what is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have actually the same problem on my developer site and i think it can be caused by

- firewalls
- http authentication on the web server
- or maybe this point [See Here](https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/907/kw/i%20receive%20no%20response%20from%20sandbox%20api)